# Co-equalizers in Set

Tags: category-theory

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Coequalizer.html

This link indicates how to form co-equalizer in category of Set. I have been given homework to describe co-equalizer for a variant of Set category but I am unable to understand completely how to form it in Set. Can someone please explain in "easy way" how to form co-equalizers in category Set?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you say which part of the explanation confuses you?

Comment: What is minimal equivalence relation on Y that makes $f$ and $g$ equal? More precisely, what is the canonical map $c$ in this case?

Comment: The minimal equivalence relation is... the minimal equivalence relation. If you don't understand that then the problem is not with category theory. The canonical map is simply the quotient map taking an element $x$ to its equivalence class $[x]$.

Comment: I meant how to define the equivalence relation ~ here. Is it right to define $y_1$ ~ $y_2$ when $f(x)=g(x)$ for all $x\in X$? Is it minimal?

Comment: What you write makes no sense. $y_1\sim y_2$ has no letter in common with $f(x)=g(x)$. You start with a relation that makes $f(x)\sim g(x)$ for each $x\in X$. Chances are, this by itself will not be an equivalence relation, so you consider the *smallest* equivalence relation that contains all pairs of the form $(f(x),g(x))$ (the intersection of all equivalence relations that contain all such pairs). This is an equivalence relation, and its the smallest equivalence relation in which $f(x)\sim g(x)$ holds for each $x\in X$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let $X$ and $Y$ be sets, and let $f, g : X \to Y$ be maps. The coequaliser of $f$ and $g$ is the quotient map $c : Y \to Y / \sim$, where $\sim$ is the smallest equivalence relation such that $f(x) \sim g(x)$ for all $x$ in $X$. So, for example, the following will be true:

- For all $y$ in $Y$, $y \sim y$.
- For all $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ in $X$ such that $g(x_1) = f(x_2), g(x_2) = f(x_3), \cdots, g(x_{n-1}) = f(x_n)$, we have $f(x_1) \sim g(x_n)$.
- If $g(x_1) = g(x_2)$ then $f(x_1) \sim f(x_2)$.

Working out what the equivalence relation is explicitly is not very enlightening; it is far more useful to understand the universal property of a coequaliser.

Comment: I would say that *not* working out explicitly the equivalence relation will only result in the result seeming magical. In particular, if person X cannot tell me when to elements of the equalizer are equal in terms of the initial data of the problem, it is rather hard to conclude that she has any idea of what the coequalizer is.

Comment: Why do we need of the last requirement for the equivalence relation?

Answer (score 3):

The key point in building the coequalizer is to figure out the $"\sim"$ [equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation) relation. This simply mean that we need to somehow partition the set Y.

Note that the *smallest* the equivalence relation, the largest the number of partitions. Thus, our goal is to partition Y as far as possible under certain conditions.

The largest number of partitions happens when we put each element of Y into one partition. However, we need to merge some of these partitions to satisfy the coequalizer definition. To this end, I think following the following pseudo code will will provide us with the desired partions:

```
$P = empty     // keep the partitions
for each $y in Y{
   build a new partition called $p; 
   put $y in $p;
   put $p in $P;  
}
for each $x in X { 
       merge the partitions in $P that contain either f(x) or g(x);
 }
```

The above pseudo code build your partitions in Y. This might be the one that you can get with the smallest equivalence relation with the conditions explained for the coequalizer.

Answer (score 2):

Although a correct answer has already been given, I’ve just realized that there is somewhat more structural and categorical way to represent co-equalizers in $Set$.

A co-equalizer is a co-limit of the diagram: $A \rightrightarrows D$.

Recall, that diagrams $A \rightrightarrows D$ in $Set$ are just graphs. Strictly speaking, they form a category of directed irreflexive graphs $Set^{\circ \rightrightarrows \circ}$ but since we do not distinguish between $f: A \to D$ and $g: A \to D$, we can treat arrows $a \in A$ just as “edges” between dots $d \in D$.

It is clear that for any co-equalizing $e^{\prime}$ $A \overset{f; e^{\prime}}{\underset{g; e^{\prime}} \rightrightarrows} E^{\prime} $ is also a graph. Moreover, since $f;e^{\prime} = g;e^{\prime} $ this graph is discrete (contains only loops). Also $e^{\prime}$ defines a morphism in the category of graphs since it clearly doesn’t break arrows.

Now, our task is to find the finest epic morphism $e$ (co-equalizers are always epic) from the graph $A \overset{f}{\underset{g} \rightrightarrows} D$ to some discrete graph $A \overset{f;e}{\underset{g;e} \rightrightarrows} E$. The most natural way is to simply factorize dots of $D$ by a relation of “being connected by arrows from $A$”. Which gives the desired construction.

---

I’ve found quite enlightening to think about diagrams of form $A \overset{f}{\underset{g} \rightrightarrows} E$ in any category as a “connection of two ways of comparing $A$ and $D$ by means of $A$” and co-equalizer as a minimal way to “collapse” $D$ over this connection.

Comment: I want to understand your final two paragraphs, as they do feel enlightening. But I'm not sure I get some of your notation and use of types. I'll be brief: please don't mind.
(1) What do A and D stand for? 
(2) I think of a diagram as in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagram_(category_theory) : functor from index category to collection, in this case of sets & set morphisms. Are you doing that? 
(3) Because with your e′ A⇉g;e′f;e′E′ , you seem to be either attaching labels ("f", "g", "e'") or saying the arrows are functions. 
(4) How are arrows a∈A edges between dots d∈D?

Comment: Also, are you saying the same as https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Category_Theory/Products_and_Coproducts#Alternative_Definition does with its "product-maker category", but for coequalisers rather than products?

Answer (score 1):

You can get a description of how to calculate coequalisers on finite sets from the book *Computational Category Theory* by David Rydeheard and Rod Burstall. (Acknowledgements also to D. T. Sannella and others.) It's available at [http://www.cs.man.ac.uk/~david/categories/](http://www.cs.man.ac.uk/%7Edavid/categories/) , together with code for the programs therein contained. The algorithm for coequalisers is on page 102 of the PDF.

Here are two simple coequalisers, with the one on the right partitioning by coalescing two elements. This isn't the only way to think about coequalisers: as Zhen Lin says, it's good to think about their universality. But it's also good to see details. For example, if you calculate several coequalisers on the same sets but with different parallel arrows you get a feel for how the size of the equivalence relation varies with the number of partitions, as pointed out by qartal. [image]

Answer (score 0):

One particular example of coequalizer may be known to you. Let's say we are in the category of vector spaces, or abelian groups. Let $f: V \longrightarrow W$ be any linear map (group morphism) and $0: V \longrightarrow W$ the zero map (morphism), that is, the map which sends every element of $V$ to zero. Then, the coequalizer of $f$ and $0$ is just the cokernel of $f$, $\mathrm{cok}\ f = W / \mathrm{im}\ f$.