# Coequalizers in the Category of Sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, category-theory

This is an elementary question but I cannot get my head around it:

According to the definition of Coequalizers (specifically for the category of Finite Sets), what are the elements of the objects? Different sources talk about equivalence classes and then quotients but they are confusing to understand. Can anyone give a simple example with example Sets and functions even if it is not 100% mathematically right, just to get the idea?

[image]

Comment: "what are the elements of the objects?" Objects have no elements. Repeat the first pages of your introduction to category theory. Also you should make your question more precise. Also indicate in how far http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/90013 hasn't answered your question (if you had done any search before).

Comment: Hi. Well I meant the elements inside the object sets of the category of FinSets as an example to show how the coequliser 'works' in the above structure. I understand that normally we abstract away from what is inside the sets if sets are objects but I think it would help to understand the logic

Answer (score 6):

In $\Bbb{Set}$, the coequalizer object $Q$ of functions $f,g:X\to Y$ is the *quotient set* $Y/\sim$ where $\sim$ is the equivalence relation generated by $f(x)\sim g(x)$ for all $x\in X$.

This means that the elements of $Q$ are basically the elements of $Y$, but $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are regarded *the same* element in $Q$, for every $x$, i.e. $f(x)=g(x)$ holds in $Q$. [Precisely this would be $q(f(x))=q(g(x))$.]

The equalizer of $f,g$ is the *subset* of $X$ on which $f$ and $g$ agree ('*asking*' for those $x\in X$ which make $f(x)=g(x)$).

The coequalizer of $f,g$ is the *quotient* of $Y$ ('*forcing*' $f(x)=g(x)$ for all $x\in X$, thus perhaps collapsing some elements together).